# Asymmetric encryption in lazarus

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Is there any library for lazarus ( free pascal ) which supports asymmetric encryption?

Comment: You may have a look here: http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/crypt_en.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make asymmetric encryption in Lazarus you need to integrate openssl.

If you use windows download http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1e.exe

Now you can use openssl in lazarus like this:

```
uses ..., Process;

...

procedure encrypt_file();
var hProcess : TProcess;
begin
  hProcess := TProcess.Create(nil);
  hProcess.Executable := 'openssl';
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('aes-256-cbc');
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('-a -salt');
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('-in secrets.txt'); //input file
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('-out secrets.txt.enc'); //output file  
  hProcess.Options := hProcess.Options + [poWaitOnExit, poUsePipes]; 
  hProcess.Execute;
end;

procedure decrypt_file();
var hProcess : TProcess;
begin
  hProcess := TProcess.Create(nil);
  hProcess.Executable := 'openssl';
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('aes-256-cbc');
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('-d -salt');
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('-in secrets.txt.enc'); //input file
  hprocess.Parameters.Add('-out secrets.txt.new'); //output file  
  hProcess.Options := hProcess.Options + [poWaitOnExit, poUsePipes]; 
  hProcess.Execute;
end;
```

Note: The example is for symmetric encryption for asymmetric read this article:
http://www.devco.net/archives/2006/02/13/public_-_private_key_encryption_using_openssl.php

Comment: Well, you don't need to use openssl? There are encryption libraries like dpcrypt and some built into FPC itself...

Comment: @reiniero And what are they called?

Answer (score 1):

Lazarus/FPC comes with openssh headers afaik. It might not be necessary to go the external program route.

Comment: Some of the TCP/IP socket suites (LNET,Indy,Synapse) might make use of it. Study their code.